# Restore all items in a list to a previous version

Tags: sharepoint-online, restore, version-history

We ran into an issue were someone ran a flow to update all items in a list (~1300) that ended up resetting all value in a column to the default value.

We have versioning enabled on the list but I can't find a method to restore the version for all items and going one by one is going to be driving us nuts.

Not sure if it matters but there have been changes to some items since the issue update ran, we don't care to maintain that data, but the result is that we can't say let roll back all items 1 version. We need to restore them to the last version before the rouge update (we know the date and time stamp for it)

The site is in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score -1):

This is Venkatesh,

As per my knowledge and also done the same process it works

go to -->site content--> view all site content we can see the "Version History"-->...(eclipse) select that select that ""Version History"   in that we can select the date or month then will come the Previous version of the data

Comment: There is not "View All Site Content" option under "Site Contents".